# HTTP client saving download metadata

Tags: ssl, http, download, url, file-metadata

I am looking for a way to download files from the Web, while saving download metadata, like the requested URI, the returned status code and maybe even TLS certificate information (server certificate details, negotiated algorithms for download session) alongside the file.

Ideally saving the metadata into the same file using extended attributes.

Is there a simple way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -v "$URL" > $FILE 2> $FILE.meta
```

Read 'man curl' for options.